# Does "a IN ('x','y') OR a = 'z' " equal: "a IN ('x', 'y', 'z')"?

Tags: sql, logic

I'm trying to clarify a sql logic issue.

My understanding is that the above is correct.

```
'a' evaluates to TRUE if IN ('x', 'y') 
'a' also evaluates to TRUE if it equals z.
```

Therefore it's the same logic as:

```
 'a' IN ('x', 'y', 'z')".
```

Comment: yes they are same.

Comment: Thank you. I thought so but was being told otherwise and thought I might be crazy. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those are the same. Just more complicated.